# Decrypt with PHP, Encrypt with Javascript (cryptoJS)

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, cryptojs

In my case, **encrypted data is encrypted by cryptoJS**, also I want to Decrypt using PHP.

So [I wrote a question about this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54091653/decrypt-with-php-encrypt-with-javascript-cryptojs). However, I haven't found any solution.
I tried several times to find the answer, but the decryption failed.

The data encrypted by CryptoJS provided by the server is encrypted as follows.

```
var encryptedParam = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify({"user_pw":"test"}), "1234");
```

The encrypted data in the code is a JSON object, and the key is `1234`.

Also, my PHP code as follows.

```
mcrypt_decrypt(
  MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, 
  '1234', 
  '-------encrypted data---------', 
  MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, 
  mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(
     MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), MCRYPT_RAND)
);
```

But it does not work the way I want. No matter what, I can't make this to work. Please help me.

Comment: Maybe kind of unrelated, but... `mcrypt_*` family of functions is **deprecated** in PHP 7.1+. I would argue against using it.

Comment: @Smuuf but my server is too old.. 5.3ver.. T_T.. I have no choice but to use 'A'.

Comment: Well, these things happen. Still, if you have `openssl_*` functions available _(should be from PHP 5.3.3+)_ I would try these. Working with `openssl_*` is even more friendly than with `mcrypt_*`, from my experience.

Comment: It seems you're not using an IV. You can set an IV with those parameters: `{ mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, iv: iv}`, and make sure to use the same IV in your PHP code. `mcrypt_decrypt` shouldn't be a problem here because you're using `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` which is AES, but it would be best to update to `openssl` if you can.

Comment: @t.m.adam thanks for your comment. However, that Js code is lambda server in the company.
I have to use version 5.3 of PHP to decode the keys in this format.
It is absolutely necessary to answer this question.

Comment: @Smuuf I checked it again, but unfortunately, the 5.2.12 version. thanks a lot for your comment.... T_T

Comment: The problem is that CBC requires an IV. I'm not very familiar with Crypto-JS, but I guess that it either creates an IV (somehow, propably random) or it uses ECB, which is the only mode that doesn't require an IV/nonce.

Comment: use ECB if you don't want to use IV but then it's less secure